# How can i get data from a servlet into a JSP page?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a small sql servlet application that takes in a SQL command from a text area in an html page, sends the command to a servlet that makes an sql connection and puts in the resultset into an arraylist. I have all of that down, and i can print column names to the browser in the java servlet class. One thing i need to do is print the results into a table using a JSP page. The JSP page will look just like the html page we first used. I can not figure out how i am going to get the arraylist from the servlet to the JSP page to be displayed to the user.

Here is the HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebApp</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:blue;">
    <center>
        <font color="white">
        <h1> Welcome to the Project 4 Remote Database Management System</h1>
        <hr>
        You are connected to the Project4 database. <br>Please enter any valid SQL query or update statement.<br>
        If no query/update command is given the Execute button will display all supplier information in the database. <br>All execution results will appear below. 
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="NewServlet" method="post">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="60"name="command"></textarea>
            <br>
             <button type="submit">Execute Query</button>
             <button type="submit">Clear Command</button>
       </form>
        <hr>
        <h1>Database Results</h1>
        </font>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author KJ4CC
 */
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
     Connection connection;
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            String command = request.getParameter("command");
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            sqlConnection(command);
           //prints out column names into the browser. 
                out.println(columnNames);

        }
    }
    public void sqlConnection(String command){
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project3";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "Brandy?1994";
        ResultSet rs;
         try {
             Class.forName(driver);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         try {
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         Statement stmt;
         try {
             stmt = connection.createStatement();
             rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);
             int colNum = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

                    for (int i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {

                        columnNames.add(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i+1));


                    }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Here is the start of the JSP page:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>WebApp</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:blue;">
        <center>
            <font color="white">
            <h1> Welcome to the Project 4 Remote Database Management System</h1>
            <hr>
            You are connected to the Project4 database. <br>Please enter any valid SQL query or update statement.<br>
            If no query/update command is given the Execute button will display all supplier information in the database. <br>All execution results will appear below. 
            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="NewServlet" method="post">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="60"name="command"></textarea>
                <br>
                 <button type="submit">Execute Query</button>
                 <button type="submit">Clear Command</button>
           </form>
            <hr>
            <h1>Database Results</h1>

           <%
    DO TABLE STUFF HERE TO OUTPUT SQL RESULTS
%>

            </font>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I think i will create a javaBean to store the arrays so that the JSP page can access the column arraylist. Then use a for loop to iterate through the array list so that i can create the table columns. **how could i link the JSP page to the servlet so that if can get the information needed?**

I have to do the sql connection in the servlet and cannnot make the connection in the JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your servlet method, set attribute in page context as below

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
.... // find out what to put
req.getPageContext.setAttribute('some', objectYouFound);
```

In your jsp, use el to access the variable:

```
${some}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet, store the data in a request attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("rows", rows);
```

In the JSP, use [the JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to loop over the rows:

```
<c:forEach var="row" value="${rows}">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

Do NOT use Java scriptlets in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues with your current code:

(1) A single servlet instance will be shared across all request threads, so you should NOT create the instance variables for a servlet class i.e.,

```
Connection connection;
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
```

These two variables should be created inside your `processRequest`() method so that they will be local to each request thread.

(2) You are ONLY querying the META DATA of the table, so you can display only column names, but if you wanted to fetch the data as well, you need to use `resultSetObj.hasNext()` and then use `next()` method like below:

```
    while (rs.hasNext())
    {
       String X = rs.getString("empno");
       //Retrieve all data
       //add to a bean object
       //add to list
    }
   //Now return the list which contains the data
```

You can look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) for a good example.

(3) Use the `request.setAttribute` to set the results to the request object and then you can retrieve to the next JSP (results) page.

Comment: Good point! I did notice that each time i would reload the page, i would have the same column names appended to the vector!